# Why is Chrome shifting my form label and select when the select receives focus?

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, css-float

I have a simple address entry form. In IE9 and Firefox 10.0.2, the form displays perfectly fine.

In Chrome, the form displays fine upon initial load. But, when I give the one SELECT focus, the label and SELECT both shift to the right about 100px:

[image: Chrome Screen Grab]

It gets even worse when I attempt to use Chrome's Auto-fill:

[image: Chrome Auto-fill Screen Grab]

So random. Now, I could iterate through the entire HTML layout, CSS rules, and JavaScript/jQuery being used, but, what I'm looking for are some ideas about what might be causing this. Below is the HTML and CSS that are being used for the elements in question.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="editAddressForm" name="editAddressForm" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Name/Attention *:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input name="shipToName" value="#FORM.shipToName#" maxlength="40" />
        </cfoutput>
        <br />
        <label>Company:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToCompany"
            value"#FORM.shipToCompany#"
            maxlength="40" />
        </cfoutput>&nbsp;
        <br />
        <label>Address 1 *:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToAddressLine1"
            value="#FORM.shipToAddressLine1#"
            maxlength="40" />
        </cfoutput>&nbsp;
        <br />
        <label>Address 2:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToAddressLine2"
            value="#FORM.shipToAddressLine2#"
            maxlength="40" />
        </cfoutput>&nbsp;
        <br />
        <label>Address 3:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToAddressLine3"
            value="#FORM.shipToAddressLine3#"
            maxlength="40" />
        </cfoutput>
        <br />
        <label>City *:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input name="shipToCity" value="#FORM.shipToCity#" maxlength="30" />
        </cfoutput>
        <br />
        <label>State *:</label>
        <oftags:selectState name="shipToState" selectedValue="#FORM.shipToState#">
        <br />
        <label>Zip *:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToPostalCode"
            value="#FORM.shipToPostalCode#"
            maxlength="10" />
        </cfoutput>
        <br />
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToPhone"
            value="#REQUEST.UDFLib.String.PhoneFormat(FORM.shipToPhone)#"
            maxlength="16"/>
        </cfoutput>
        <br />
        <label>E-Mail:</label>
        <cfoutput>
        <input
            name="shipToEmailAddress"
            value="#FORM.shipToEmailAddress#"
            maxlength="60"/>
        </cfoutput>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#editAddressForm {
    text-align: left;
    width: 720px;
}

#editAddressForm label {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 6px 0;
}

#editAddressForm fieldset {
    border: none;
}

#editAddressForm fieldset input,
#editAddressForm fieldset select {
    width: 200px;
}

#editAddressForm br {
    clear: left;
}

#editAddressForm select  {
    margin: 3px 0;
}
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        /*
         * Page Initialization
         */
        $("input[name='shipToName']").focus();
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#stateSelect").selectSelectedValue();
    });
</script>
```

jquery-select.js:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        selectSelectedValue: function(callback) {
            var _selectedValue = $(this).prop("selectedValue");

            $(this).find("option").each(function(){
                if ($(this).text() == _selectedValue)
                    $(this).prop("selected", true);
            });

            $(this).change();

            if($.isFunction(callback))
                callback.call(this);
        },

        selectDefaultOption: function(callback) {
            $(this).find("option:first").prop("selected", true);

            $(this).change();

            if($.isFunction(callback))
                callback.call(this);
        },

        disable: function(){
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        },

        enable: function(){
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Would you mind removing the ColdFusion-isms unless they're relevant to the question?

Comment: Can you post the outputted HTML instead of the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a `line-height` in CSS on your `#editAddressForm label`, or better yet, the parent containers for the labels and inputs. Also try `display: block` on the parent elements and set a height and/or `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: display: block on the parent containers worked. I wrote it without parent containers originally, but this looks the same and fixes this issue. thanks.